# Netplan is not working after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: networking, server, upgrade, 20.04, netplan

I upgraded my server from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. After the update I don't have any internet connection to the server anymore. Probably something went wrong, but still after searching the whole day, I don't find a solution or the log where I can find more information.

So if I have a look at `ip address show` I will find [two interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DT66.png). (Sorry for the images, but since I cannot connect via ssh it's not so easy to copy and paste.)
Here I am missing my external ip address. So I looked into `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`. Here I can find my [external ip address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cag0L.png).

Now I ran `netplan --debug apply` and getting [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNEfv.png) but `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.link` [is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auT7l.png).

What have I done wrong or where can I look to see what is wrong?

kernel: 4.15.0-128-generic
ubuntu version: 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. My yml-file was missing the way to the gateway.